# Casting AnyObject to Specific Class

Tags: swift, casting, socket.io, anyobject

I'm using socket.io Swift Library. With the following line of code,

```
socket.on("info") { (dataArray, socketAck) -> Void in
            let user = dataArray[0] as? User
            print(user._id)
}
```

`dataArray[0]` is a valid object but `user` appears to be **nil** after **casting**.

Since `dataArray[0]` returns as an `AnyObject`, 
how can i cast `AnyObject` to `User` Object?. Or somehow manage to do what i want with a different approach?

[image: Socket Class]

[image: User Class]

Comment: An optional downcast using `as?` will return `nil` if the cast fails.  What is `dataArray[0].dynamicType`?  Are you sure it's a `User`?

Comment: hey @JAL, dataArray is [AnyObject], dataArray[0] is AnyObject when i look at the debugger but this line print(dataArray[0].dynamicType) prints out "__NSDictionaryM" i am confused

Comment: Looks like `dataArray` is actually an array of dictionaries and not `User` objects like you think.  Try casting `dataArray[0]` as `[String : AnyObject]` and printing the keys and values.

Comment: let test = dataArray[0] as [String : AnyObject]; when i do print(test.values), prints out "LazyMapCollection<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, AnyObject>(_base: " which i do not really understand @JAL

Comment: Are you sure this code does compile? Because `user` should be an optional and you are accessing its `_id` property without optional chaining or unwrapping.

Comment: yes it compiles, but user returns nil instead of giving errors @appzYourLife

Comment: I am pretty sure this code cannot compile. There is a compile error here `print(user._id)`. This is the error `error: value of optional type 'User?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?`

Comment: i get no compile errors, but if so, do you have any ideas on the solution? @appzYourLife

Comment: @SerhanOztekin: Could you please paste a screenshot of your Xcode where I can see that snipped of code?

Comment: Sure thing, but which part do you want? cause the screenshot of the part i'm having trouble with will be the same as the above code. @appzYourLife

Comment: @SerhanOztekin: The screenshot of exactly the snippet you added to your question. I would also need to see the code for the `User` class. Thank you.

Comment: Screenshots added, thanks @appzYourLife

Comment: @SerhanOztekin: Oohh! As I suspected it is `user!._id` and not `user._id` ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Since after this line

```
let user = dataArray[0] as? User
```

you have a `nil` value inside `user` it means that you don't have a `User` value at the first position of `dataArray`.

Since `dataArray` comes from a server (as I guess) it probably contains a serialized version of `User`.

Now we really need to know what really dataArray[0] is. However...

### if dataArray[0] contains NSData

In this case try this

```
let json = JSON(dataArray[0] as! NSData)
let user = User(json:json)
```

Comment: hello, let json = JSON(dataArray[0]) line gives me this error : argument labels(_:) do not match any available overloads.

Comment: @SerhanOztekin: Please try `let json = JSON(dataArray[0] as! NSData)`

Comment: @SerhanOztekin: Ok so the first element of your array is not `NSData`. Please run this and let me know what you see into the log `print(list[0].dynamicType)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a constructor that accept AnyObject and read data in it.
I guess in this case `dataArray[0]` is an JSON Object.

```
class User {
  init(data: [String: AnyObject]) {
     username = data["username"] as? String ?? ""
  }
}
```

Comment: i already have one for json. Goes like this: init?(json: JSON) {
        self._id = "_id" <~~ json }  Should i make an other one?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i manage mine:

```
// Structure used as parameter
struct InfoStruct {
var nome: String = ""
var sobrenome:String = ""
var nascimentoTimestamp: NSNumber = 0

init() {

}

// Struct to AnyObject
func toAnyObject() -> Any {
    var dic = [String:AnyObject?]()

    if (nome != "") { dic["nome"] = nome as AnyObject }
    if (sobrenome != "") { dic["sobrenome"] = sobrenome as AnyObject }
    if (nascimentoTimestamp != 0) { dic["nascimentoTimestamp"] = nascimentoTimestamp as AnyObject }

    return dic
}

// AnyObject to Struct
func fromAnyObject(dic:[String:AnyObject]) -> InfoStruct {
    var retorno = InfoStruct()

    if (dic["nome"] != nil) { retorno.nome = dic["nome"] as? String ?? "" }
    if (dic["sobrenome"] != nil) { retorno.sobrenome = dic["sobrenome"] as? String ?? "" }
    if (dic["nascimentoTimestamp"] != nil) { retorno.nascimentoTimestamp = dic["nascimentoTimestamp"] as? NSNumber ?? 0 }

    return retorno
} }


// User class
class Usuario: NSObject {
var key: String
var admin: Bool
var info: InfoStruct // Struct parameter

init(_ key: String?) {
    self.key = key ?? ""
    admin = false
    info = InfoStruct() // Initializing struct
}

// From Class to AnyObject
func toAnyObject() -> Any {
    var dic = [String:AnyObject?]()

    if (key != "") { dic["key"] = key as AnyObject }
    if (admin != false) { dic["admin"] = admin as AnyObject }
    dic["info"] = info.toAnyObject() as AnyObject // Struct

    return dic
}

// From AnyObject to Class
func fromAnyObject(dic:[String:AnyObject]) -> Usuario {
    let retorno = Usuario(dic["key"] as? String)

    if (dic["key"] != nil) { retorno.key = dic["key"] as? String ?? "" }
    if (dic["admin"] != nil) { retorno.admin = dic["admin"] as? Bool ?? false }
    if (dic["info"] != nil) { retorno.info = InfoStruct.init().fromAnyObject(dic: dic["info"] as! [String : AnyObject]) } // Struct

    return retorno
} }

// Using
let dao = FirebaseDAO.init(_type: FirebaseDAOType.firebaseDAOTypeUser)
dao.loadValue(key: uid) { (error, values:[String : AnyObject]) in
     if error == nil {
          let user = Usuario(values["key"] as? String).fromAnyObject(dic: values)
     }
}
```

I hope it helps!